# Find all but allowed characters in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a query I've been trying to make, it's supposed to pull all rows that do not contain characters we do not want.

```
SELECT NID FROM NOTES WHERE NOTE LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z#.;:/^\(\)\@\ \  \\\-]%'
```

That should return any rows that do not contain

```
0-9 a-z A-z . : ; ^ & @ \ / ( ) #
```

But any time i add one of these below it fails

```
$ [ ] ?
```

Even trying to escape them either by \ or [[ doesn't seem to work properly. I only have access to stock SQL install.

Comment: A note on the regex tag for this question. Even though some of the expressions for LIKE look like regex, it is not. I's SQL Server's own regex-ish expressions.

Comment: "it fails": *How* does it fail? Do you get an error? What is the error message? Or does it run but the results are incorrect? Can you show some example input data, the full query you ran, the incorrect result you get, and the result you wanted?

Comment: @MarkByers No error messages. It just returns no rows at all, despite having added characters that are not within the allowable range (french style..etc)

Comment: You question is very unclear. Please state clearly and unambiguously 1) Some example data from your database 2) Which rows you want to be returned from that example data and 3) Which rows actually get returned by your query.

Comment: @MarkByers I have thousands of rows of [this type of data](https://gist.github.com/3006785). I need to make sure they only contain certain characters. A-Z a-z 0-9 [ ] ( ) { } " ' / \ ? @ # $ % ^ & * ! ~ . : ; < > - _ and spaces. Otherwise i need to know about them to get rid of them as they cause issues with another application. Bad data is anything outside of those listed above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it's supposed to pull all rows that **do not contain** characters we do not want.

To find rows that *contain* `x` you can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE col LIKE '%x%'
```

To find rows that *do not contain* `x` you can use `NOT LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE col NOT LIKE '%x%'
```

So your query should use `NOT LIKE` because you want rows that *don't contain* something:

```
SELECT NID FROM NOTES WHERE NOTE NOT LIKE '%[0-9a-zA-Z#.;:/^\(\)\@\ \  \\\-]%'
```

---

> That should return any rows that do not contain
>
> ```
> 0-9 a-z A-z . : ; ^ & @ \ / ( ) #
> ```

No. Because of the `^` at the start, it returns the rows that don't contain *characters except those*. Those characters you listed are the characters that *are* allowed.

Comment: My understanding was that the caret symbol acts the same as the word NOT. Any ideas on properly escaping the [ and ] ?

Comment: @iarp: No, it's two completely different things. `NOT` is a boolean operator. Adding it at the front of the where clause changes which rows are returned (the rows that *don't* match the condition are returned). `[^...]` means "every character except ...". It's not the same. You can easily verify this for yourself by testing both and seeing that they give different results. You need to figure out the basics first. Try to understand what `NOT` means and what `[^...]` means before you start working out how to escape things. If your basic query is wrong, the advanced part *definitely* won't work.

Comment: [MS own help site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) lists "Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).". And the example given along with the description fit what i did above without the need of NOT. Right now when i read yours, NOT LIKE [^...], it is like NOT NOT which would return everything between []. I do not want anything within the square brackets, hence my use of ^ instead of NOT LIKE.

Comment: @iarp: But what you are suggesting won't work! You say "I do not want". This translates to "WHERE NOT". And "anything within the square brackets" translates to "[abc]". With that example you never need to use `^`. "Right now when i read yours, NOT LIKE [^...], it is like NOT NOT which would return everything between []" That's not true. You can easily verify this for yourself by testing it. `LIKE '%[a]%'` and `NOT LIKE '%[^a]%` give different results. The first one matches `cat` and the second one doesn't. Proof: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/2213